# Find the value of $k$ in a joint probability density function

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with a joint probability density function given by: $f(x, y) =ke^{-(x+y)}$ for   $0\leq  x < \infty$ and $0\leq y <\infty$.

a) Find $k $.

b) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

To solve for $k$, would I just take the double integral of $e^{-(x+y)}$ both from 0 to infinity?

Not 100% sure if my approach to this is correct. Also how do I tell if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards a) you are right: we need that
$$1=k\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-(x+y)}dxdy=k\left(\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x}dx\right)^2.$$
As regards b) first find the individual densities:
$$f_X(x)=k\int_{y=0}^{+\infty}e^{-(x+y)}dy, \quad
f_Y(y)=k\int_{x=0}^{+\infty}e^{-(x+y)}dx.$$
$X$ and $Y$ are independent iff
$$f(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y).$$

Comment: @quwerty Any further doubt?

Comment: Nope, everything makes perfect sense. Thanks!